# What's the equivalent of NSHomeDirectory() in CoreFoundation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, sandbox, core-foundation

I have a C library I'm modifying, as little as possible, to add a feature and get that to run properly on iOS. It is working fine on iOS 5.1, but breaking on iOS 6 because it's required to write a small temporary file, and I think there is an issue w/ Entitlements with where it used to write (/tmp/some.file).

I know that NSHomeDirectory() will give me the sandbox root from objectiveC, but it requires objectiveC / Foundation to run. How can I get the sandbox root using only C / CoreFoundation calls?

Comment: Do you have access to `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`? Or does that have the same problem?

Comment: Are you actually looking for the home directory, or just a temporary directory to store a file in?

Comment: @Rob A NS prefix implies Foundation.

Comment: @Macmade Thanks. I was hoping that because it was a C call, not an Objective-C method, that he could access it via Core Foundation, which he said he could use.

Comment: @Rob Yep, but as the OP said that the code was in a C library, it's better not to mix IMHO. That would cause including un-needed headers from Foundation, as well as un-needed linking with the Foundation framework, from the library.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I was just looking for any place to write a temp file to momentarily.

Comment: @Macmade, that's correct, thanks, I am looking for something starting with CF rather than NS.

Comment: Though any app that runs on iOS will link against Foundation anyway. You can't really avoid it.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan True for an application. But not necessarily for a library compiled as a separate target. Even if, at the end, everything will be linked with Foundation, as we can only create static libs on iOS.

Comment: @Macmade: Kinda what I meant--the end product will ultimately have to link against Foundation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CoreFoundation equivalent of `NSHomeDirectory()` is `CFCopyHomeDirectoryURL()`. It is available since iOS 5 and the only place where it is “documented” is in the [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html).

If you want the temporary directory without hardcoding the `tmp` string, then you may want to use `confstr` with the `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` constant and fallback to the `TMPDIR` environment variable if the confstr call fails:

```
char tmpdir[PATH_MAX];
size_t n = confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR, tmpdir, sizeof(tmpdir));
if ((n <= 0) || (n >= sizeof(tmpdir)))
    strlcpy(tmpdir, getenv("TMPDIR"), sizeof(tmpdir));
CFURLRef tmp = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8 *)tmpdir, strlen(tmpdir), true);
```

Comment: It took a while to verify but this does seem to be a bit more precise of an answer (well, two answers actually - but the first is what I'm referring to) so I'm switching the Chosen Answer to this one. They're all correct as far as I can tell though.

Comment: use n > sizeof(tmpdir) instead of n >= sizeof(tmpdir)

Comment: You should probably add a final fallback to `/tmp` in case that `confstr()` fails and `$TMPDIR` is not set. This is better than failing entirely.

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/gen/confstr.c.auto.html suggests that confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR) falls back to getEnv("TMPDIR") on its own.

Answer (score 7):

There is no "home" directory on iOS.

Your app is in a sandbox, so you don't have access to `/tmp`.

Instead, you have a `tmp` directory inside your application's sandbox.

You can use [CFBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html) to get the path to your app.
The temp folder can then be found by adding `../tmp/`.

Basically:

```
CFBundleRef         bundle;
CFURLRef            url;
CFStringRef         bundlePath;
CFStringRef         tmpRelPath;
CFMutableStringRef  tmpPath;

bundle      = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
url         = CFBundleCopyBundleURL( bundle );
bundlePath  = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath( url, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle );
tmpRelPath  = CFSTR( "/../tmp/" );
tmpPath     = CFStringCreateMutable( kCFAllocatorDefault, CFStringGetLength( bundlePath ) + CFStringGetLength( tmpRelPath ) );

CFStringAppend( tmpPath, bundlePath );
CFStringAppend( tmpPath, tmpRelPath );

CFShow( tmpPath );

CFRelease( url );
CFRelease( bundlePath );
CFRelease( tmpPath );
```

Comment: This looks like just what I wanted, thanks - I'll let you know how it works once I try it.

Comment: I'm still having problems writing to it (getting a bad access on fprintf), but the above code does seem to correctly get a location inside the sandbox, so I'm marking this as correct. Thanks again.